# Spring boot file upload with form data?

Tags: spring-boot, angular4-forms

Normally a form contains some basic fields like

```
firstName       (TextBox)
LastName        (TextBox)
address         (TextArea)
profile image   (file)
```

when a user clicked on submit button all the form details should be stored together. so i created one pojo like

```
class UserInfo {
private String firstName       
private String laseName 
private String address    
private File profileImage  
}
```

but whatever example i found on google are not handling multi-part with info object. for example

```
@PostMapping("/api/userInfo")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFileMulti(
        @RequestParam("extraField") String extraField,
        @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] uploadfiles) {
}
```

so is there is any way where we can store form details with file control data like

```
@PostMapping("/api/userInfo")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFullForm(
   @RequestBody("userInfo") UserInfo  userInfo ) {
}
```

I am using `springboot` and `angular4`.  any example or link that can help me.

Comment: I looked for that solution too. But coulnd't find, which is pretty surprising.